# Question about a C construct

Tags: c

I always thought I knew C very well until I saw something like this in another post:

```
struct foo {
    int x:1;
};
```

I would really like to know the purpose of the :1. Can anybody clue me in? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

bitfield.
x is 1 bit long.

> Each field is accessed and manipulated
>   as if it were an ordinary member of a
>   structure. The keywords signed and
>   unsigned mean what you would expect,
>   except that it is interesting to note
>   that a 1-bit signed field on a two's
>   complement machine can only take the
>   values 0 or -1. The declarations are
>   permitted to include the const and
>   volatile qualifiers.
>
> The main use of bitfields is either to
>   allow tight packing of data or to be
>   able to specify the fields within some
>   externally produced data files. C
>   gives no guarantee of the ordering of
>   fields within machine words, so if you
>   do use them for the latter reason, you
>   program will not only be non-portable,
>   it will be compiler-dependent too. The
>   Standard says that fields are packed
>   into ‘storage units’, which are
>   typically machine words. The packing
>   order, and whether or not a bitfield
>   may cross a storage unit boundary, are
>   implementation defined. To force
>   alignment to a storage unit boundary,
>   a zero width field is used before the
>   one that you want to have aligned.
>
> Be careful using them. It can require
>   a surprising amount of run-time code
>   to manipulate these things and you can
>   end up using more space than they
>   save.
>
> Bit fields do not have addresses—you
>   can't have pointers to them or arrays
>   of them.

http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/bitfields.html

Comment: Thank you! But what advantage does this have over just declaring it a regular integer?

Comment: @Joe M: It potentially uses less space.  It's more useful when you have multiple bitfields, since the compiler will (hopefully) use less memory per struct in that case than multiple ints.

Comment: You can access the fields individually instead of writing bit-manipulating stuff every time you want to access them.

Answer (score 3):

these are bit fields. in structs you can define how many bits are assigned to the variable (overriding the standard for the variable type)

in the example above x only uses 1 byte and can thus only take the value 0 or 1.

see the following example from [the C book](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/bitfields.html). follow the link for more information.

```
struct {
      /* field 4 bits wide */
      unsigned field1 :4;
      /*
       * unnamed 3 bit field
       * unnamed fields allow for padding
       */
      unsigned        :3;
      /*
       * one-bit field
       * can only be 0 or -1 in two's complement!
       */
      signed field2   :1;
      /* align next field on a storage unit */
      unsigned        :0;
      unsigned field3 :6;
}full_of_fields;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit field that's 1 bit long. There's a good discussion on the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field).

Answer (score 0):

That syntax is used to denote bit fields (i.e. fields of bits that are narrower than the data type itself), so the "x" in your example is really using 1 bit of an int.

A more useful example might be something like

```
char x:4;
char y:4;
```

This would pack two 4-bit fields into one byte.
The advantage is, of course, to save space in architectures where every byte is critical.